# log4j configuration file and jar application

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using the log4j2 library to manage the logging process.
I created a configuration file named log4j2.xml containing the Appenders and Loggers configurations. Then, I defined a Logger in each class

```
private static Logger my_logger = LogManager.getLogger(my_class);
```

I did not specify anywhere the name of the conf file, so I think that the library implicitly get and read it.

Now, I need to provide my application in the form of a jar file, so I need to make the config file available so that the user can modify and configure it.

In my case, I suggest to create a XXX folder at the level of the jar file, containing all the configuration files used by my app.

My question is how can I say to the app "get XXX/log4j2.xml" rather than the xml contained into the jar.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html explains how Log4j2 looks for configuration file and how you can override it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

that config file must be located in the class path, if you want the app to read the configuration from any other location then you need to specify that using

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("/myPath/log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make any folder and put your property or xml file in that. In order to read the property file you can do something like this:

```
Properties objProperties = new Properties();   
 <your-class>.class.getClassLoader().getResource("folder/log4j.properties");
objProperties.load(isFile);
```

or, Also this:

```
InputStream ist = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder/log4j.properties");
```

In case of java web application please use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151832/in-java-web-application-how-to-read-log4j-xml-from-web-inb-conf-location-with-s)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar task a few weeks ago.
I solved it this way:

- Store a *template* of your log4j2.xml inside your jar files resource folder
- When running your application, check for a file named log4j2.xml in the jar files current directory
- If there is one, use that to create your logger
- If not, copy your template from within your jar to the jar files directory and then use that to create your logger.

Cheers